# Importando o pacote java.lang.*

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, import

Acrescentando os estudos em Java me deparei com um pacote tanto que especial, o `java.lang`, onde o autor do livro menciona que não precisamos realizar o `import` desse pacote.

> Há um pacote
>   especial no mundo Java chamado java.lang. Este pacote é especial
>   porque é importado automaticamente. Ainda é possível digitar esse
>   pacote em uma declaração de importação, mas você não precisa fazer
>   isso. "OCA: Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I Study"

Gostaria de entender porque apenas o pacote `java.lang.*` é o único em que não precisamos efetuar o import quando estamos desenvolvendo em Java e o que ele possui de diferencial com os demais pacotes em que precisamos importar?

Comment: É porque ela contém classes essenciais para o funcionamento da JVM, por exemplo, a classe `Object` da qual todas as outras classes do proprio java ou q vc crie deverão herdar obrigatoriamente.

Comment: @ArticunoL na verdade como a herança é automática não precisaria importar de qualquer jeito

Comment: Sem o java.lang não daria nem pra fazer o método `main`, já que o parâmetro dele é um array de `java.lang.String`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ele possui todas as principais funções do *framework* do Java e provavelmente você vai precisar de pelo menos uma função do que está nesse pacote em aplicações que não sejam absolutamente triviais e portanto teria que importá-lo, é quase impossível fazer algo útil sem usar algo dela. Ali tem o que é mais importante e foi considerado ruim ter que fazer uma importação quase obrigatória em todos os códigos, viraria uma burocracia. Todos os outros pacotes já dependem muito do tipo de aplicação, não é qualquer código que você faz IO, ou usa uma coleção de dados, ou as funções utilitárias, etc. As demais importadas automaticamente aumentariam demais a superfície de códigos importados e aumentaria a chance de conflitos e ou de ter que desligar a importação automática.

É bastante curioso o Java que é considerado verbosos adotar essa postura. C# preferiu colocar alguns nomes muitos usados na linguagem mesmo e deixar você importar tudo manualmente, por exemplo quase toda aplicação precisa ter o `using System;`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).